# Why does ImageResizer increase the loading time?

Tags: html, css, imageresizer

ImageResizer increases the loading time.

In the past, I used CSS class to resize the images. I tried to use ImageResizer to resize the image after.  Size seems to be reduced, but the loading time seems to increase.  I want to know why ImageResizer increases the loading time.

I have tried both method in same execution
**Capture1** used css class resize - time used 77ms
**Capture2** used ImageResizer resize - time used 126ms

[image]

Comment: So your question is about the loading time?

Comment: yes, in the photo can see that from 62ms to 210ms

Comment: Okay. You want to know why loading time increased?

Comment: yes. can provides how to reduce the size and load time when using imageresizer?

Comment: You expect less loading time right?  I googled it, and it says less loading time. Can you maybe run it again?

Comment: i tried several time, get the same results.

Comment: I added more tags to draw more attention.

Answer (score 2):

If [this](https://imageresizing.net/) is the ImageResizer you're talking about, I'd guess it resizes the image server-side on each request, so you're seeing the processing time in the load time.

You'll probably want to look into enabling the cache if you already haven't, so the resizing will occur only once. https://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/diskcache